# NetArchTest.Rules not asserting tests

Tags: .net-core, clean-architecture, netarchtest

I've met a cool nuget package NetArchTest.Rules, but it's seems that actually doesn't work. Cause every test that I run it shows me √ (success) which is wrong.

Maybe I do something wrong so here is my code:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTests {
    protected static Assembly DomainAssembly = typeof(IEntity<>).Assembly;
    protected static Assembly ApplicationAssembly = typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly;
    protected static Assembly[] AllAssemblies = { DomainAssembly, ApplicationAssembly };
}


public class DomainTests : BaseTests {

[TestCase]
public void Domain_Should_Not_Have_Any_Dependencies()
{
    var result =
        Types.InAssembly(DomainAssembly)
            .ShouldNot()
            .HaveDependencyOnAny("ApplicationXXX", "XXX")
            .GetResult();

    Assert.True(result.IsSuccessful); // always success
}
```

}

Here is the result of this test:

[image]

So no errors and nothing...

If any one wondered if the assembly is added to Domain for the testing purposes:
[image]

If anyone thought that it's my project:

https://github.com/matt-bentley/CleanArchitecture

Here's the project I've tested too and I'm having the same issue.